# Thousands images as textures (byte image limit reached)

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, rendering, scripting, image

I have a python scripts that creates around 3000 objects (cylinder). Each of one has assigned an image in one for the faces of the object. Each image is different (cannot be reproduced with procedural textures).

When I render the scene (cycles), it shows this message:

> ImageManager::add_image: byte image limit reached 1024, skipping ...

Only 1024 images out of ~3000 are shown, the rest are discarded. Each image (jpg) is ~4KB.

Is there a way to solve this (using blender python API)? I am running Blender 2.73.

Comment: see if [this Question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26255/cycles-gpu-doesnt-render-appended-textures) helps

Comment: I am using CPU (set up in the script), since I know GPU has a limit. I do it all as background job, since it is too consuming for a render (pre) view.

Comment: there is a workaround on BA that says : you combine multiple textures in on image than work on the UV mapping ( 4 texture in one image -> 750 image )

Comment: may be do you try to do some bake?